# How did the recent British Airways hack go down?

Tags: xss

How did the Magecart group manage to inject their malicious code **into** the source code of the BA ticketing site? I have read two articles, one of which said, it could be because BA was not checking their site assets on production. Another said that the hack was an XSS type exploit.

Which one of these two was it?

Comment: Not sure anyone here will be able to answer, since the information might not be public. Could you link to the two articles you read? It might help.

Comment: A simple search show this
https://www.riskiq.com/blog/labs/magecart-british-airways-breach/

Comment: @mootmoot - that doesn't explain how the attack on BA happened. That is only the published info on how it impacted customers.

Comment: You will rule out XSS if you read the report : riskiq inspected history data they crawled.

Comment: @mootmoot, according to this article :https://www.computerworlduk.com/security/magecart-who-what-is-behind-british-airways-attack-3683768/, "These kinds of attacks are known as "cross-site scripting" and exploit weaknesses in the code of the payment processing pages". Calls it an XSS attack.

Comment: At this point, it is of no use to speculate since BA did not (yet?) release any official technical info and I suspect, same as @Anders, that this information will most likely not be made public. So for now, the best resource is still the RiskIQ post.